# USB 3.0 problem on HP ProBook 6570b with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, 12.10, xhci-hcd

I have a problem enabling USB 3.0 on my laptop
Some relevant info:

uname -a

```
Linux HP-ProBook-6570b 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -nnk

```
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:17ab]
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:17ab]
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:17ab]
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
...
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4dfe Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp.
```

dmesg

```
[    1.152273] usb usb1: >SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.152342] hub 1-0:1.0: >USB hub found
[    1.152345] hub 1-0:1.0: >2 ports detected
[    1.152396] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >setting latency timer to 64
[    1.152399] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >EHCI Host Controller
[    1.152402] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.152419] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >debug port 2
[    1.156304] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.156307] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >irq 16, io mem 0xd4738000
[    1.168203] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: >USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.168225] usb usb2: >New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.168228] usb usb2: >New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.168231] usb usb2: >Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.168247] usb usb2: >Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.168248] usb usb2: >SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.168309] hub 2-0:1.0: >USB hub found
[    1.168311] hub 2-0:1.0: >2 ports detected
[    1.168347] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.168356] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.168374] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.168375] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >PCI INT A: no GSI
[    1.168375] 
[    1.168391] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >setting latency timer to 64
[    1.168394] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >xHCI Host Controller
[    1.168397] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.168479] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.168480] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >request interrupt 255 failed
[    1.168482] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >USB bus 3 deregistered
[    1.168493] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.168495] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >init 0000:00:14.0 fail, -22
[    1.168498] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:00:14.0 failed with error -22
[    1.168517] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
```

One more thing this laptop runs in natve UEFI mode
Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bit means that it can not allocate a GSI interrupt or a legacy interrupt for the device, which evidently makes it fail.  It is probably a kernel bug, relating to the case of UEFI and your USB3 device.

```
[    1.168374] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.168375] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: >PCI INT A: no GSI
[    1.168375]
```

Comment: Have tested it with mainline kernels in UEFI mode USB 3.0 fails in bios mode USB 3.0 Works reported it in launchpad.

Comment: Can you just use the machine in bios mode instead of UEFI until the problem naturally works its self out?

Comment: Im dual boting with windows in UEFI so swiching back and forth would be problematic (can't reinstall windows) but i can wait til the problem gets solved

Comment: I suppose there are worse things in the world than not having USB3.  Have you tried filing a bug report with Ubuntu, or the kernel team?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I was not clear enough.

The message in French and in English is the same :

- With Ubuntu 12.10/ Linux Mint 14 the usb3 didn’t worked on my ASUS Zenbook Prime UX31A :  When I plugged in my hard drive (usb3) on my computer, I couldn’t open the hard drive.
- The problem comes from the kernel included in ubuntu 12.10/linux mint 14. The basic kernel in Ubuntu 12.10 is the 3.5.0.
- To correct the problem I installed a newer kernel : I installed the 3.5.7 one and the problem was solved.

To change the kernel, it’s really easy: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

The Kernel 3.5.7 for Ubuntu 12.10/Linux mint 14: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/linux-3.5.y.z-review/current/

Is it more clear now? =$
Really sorry for my English!... I’ll try to be better…

Comment: Please edit and format the original answer, rather than write a new answer with the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information,
I had the same problem with my laptop (ASUS Zenbook Prime UX31A). The USB3 didn't work with ubuntu 12.10... I changed my kernel (I have installed the 3.5.7 linux kernel) and the problem was solved.
Maybe you should try.
Good luck!
(Sorry for my english =$... My english is so bad...)

The answer in french-----
ça va être un peu plus facile pour moi là!^^
Bon du coup petite info pour tous ceux qui ont miséré pour configurer le usb3 sur ubuntu 12.10/linux mint 14 sur un ASUS Zenbook Prime UX31A : 
Après avoir tenté pas mal de choses, j'ai opté pour une install d'un kernel plus récent. J'ai installé le 3.5.7 et le pb de l'usb3 était résolu! =D
Par contre le pb peut revenir suivant le kernel utilisé : le pb est revenu lorsque j'ai voulu passer sur le 3.6. Par contre là je suis sur le 3.7 et plus de soucis...
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/kernel
Le noyau (3.5.7) sont dispo ici : http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/linux-3.5.y.z-review/2012-11-30-quantal/

Comment: If someone could translate and edit the post for us the better:D

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed with kernel 3.8.5. Download from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/.

eRiC

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ChangeLog-3.8.5: "USB: xhci: correctly enable interrupts"